# Removing all session attributes with one command in java web

Tags: java, web

I know you can set and remove attributes from the java application using:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("name",name);
request.getSession.removeAttribute("name");
```

I'm looking for a simple way to remove all attributes from a session when the user logs out, is there any one line command? or do I have to use removeAttribute() method for each of them?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in Thymeleaf? This logic almost certainly doesn't belong there, even if it makes sense (and blindly clearing the session probably doesn't).

Comment: @chrylis because when a user logs out from my website I want to remove all attributes set for him to clear up RAM, but I guess thymeleaf adds some attributes that shouldn't be removed therefore a removeAll method doesn't exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On logout, you should be invalidating the user session, therefore, clearing up the user attributes. That way you don't have any application attributes.

Answer (score 5):

You have to use `removeAttribute()` for each of them. Note that there is no `removeAll()` or similar method in the Javadocs for [HttpSession](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html).

Your best bet is to get an `Enumeration<String>` of all attribute names with the [getAttributeNames()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) method, then iterate over each one and manually calling `removeAttribute()`.

Answer (score -1):

Try session.setMaxInactiveInterval(0);

Comment: This just invalidates the session which can be done by session.invalidate().